# What are the requirements for aircraft marker cones?

Tags: safety, airport, equipment, iata

What are the requirements on aircraft marker cones (a.k.a. safety cones) according to IATA IGOM-96, i.e. size & weight?

Comment: For those that are voting to close this question as "unclear what you're asking": The question is about the safety cones that are places around an aircraft to mark the wingtips etc. They need to have a certain size (to be visible) and a certain weight (not to be blown over the manoeuvring area in the slightest of wind), and there are possibly more requirements. The question asks about these requirements.

Answer (score 5):

According to IATA Airport Handling Manual, safety cones should

- be conical in shape
- be of a minimum height of 750 mm (22.2″)
- have a minimum base weight of 4.53 kg (10 lbs)
- be orange in color with reflective striping.

Comment: I write (non aviation) indistry specs for work . "Be conical in shape" is a spec speak equivalent of "don't be cheeky mate, you know one when you see one"

Comment: Thanks so much!!!!!!!

Comment: This is what I was searching for!!!